# Best way to render if data exists or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I have a graphql query running which loads some data. I am passing that data to a component and also passing a function I made to check against the data. If the data piece exists then render the passed in component and if not then render null.

```
export const GET_VESSEL = gql`
  query vesselById($id: ID!) {
    vesselById(id: $id) {
      flagCode
      shipName
    }
  }
`;

const checkData = (data, component) => data ? component : null;

<div>
 {checkData(flagCode, <Flag code={`${flagCode}`} height="15" />)}
 {checkData(shipName, <p>${flagCode}</p>)}
</div>
```

I wanted to know if there is a simpler way or if this is good way to do this? Or any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a reason you need `null`? The shortest form is more like `{flagCode && <Flag .... `

Comment: why you don't use the Loading state of apollo ?

Comment: @SILENT thanks for that suggestion, still a bit of a newbie so did not know I can do that. So I don't really need a function and can just inline this code.

Comment: @Abdelhedihlel I'm not sure what you mean? Also I'm a newbie with apollo and graphql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is

```
{flagCode && <Flag code={flagCode} height="15" />}
{shipName && <p>${flagCode}</p>}
```

There are limited circumstances where null is required but your example isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that

```
const checkData = (data, component) => Boolean(data) ? component : null;
```